# Не запускается приложение в эмуляторе Android

Tags: android, eclipse, monodevelop

Не удается запустить приложение в эмуляторе...

Консоль:

```
[2012-12-21 21:34:41 - test] Android Launch!
[2012-12-21 21:34:41 - test] adb is running normally.
[2012-12-21 21:34:41 - test] Performing com.example.test.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-12-21 21:34:41 - test] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'MonoForAndroid_API_14' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2012-12-21 21:34:41 - test] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MonoForAndroid_API_14'
[2012-12-21 21:34:43 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2012-12-21 21:34:43 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.

could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB - часто встречающаяся строчка в отчете
....
[2012-12-21 21:34:43 - test] New  emulator found: emulator-5554    
[2012-12-21 21:34:43 - test] Waiting    for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched... 
[2012-12-21 21:36:35 -    test] HOME is up on device    'emulator-5554' 
[2012-12-21 21:36:35 - test] Uploading test.apk onto device 'emulator-5554' 
[2012-12-21    21:36:41 - test] Failed to install    test.apk on device 'emulator-5554':    timeout 
[2012-12-21 21:36:41 - test]    Launch canceled!
```

Работаю в Эклипс. Дело в том что приложения не запускаются ни в Эклипс ни в моно(xamarin). Т.е эмулятор запускается но с обычным экраном, моего приложения как и в помине небывало.

Answer (score 1):

Походу проблема в том, что ваше приложение использует OpenGL, а эмулятор отказывается его поддерживать.

Попробуйте:

1. Запускать эмулятор отдельно и подключать к нему приложение когда эмулятор уже запущен
2. Поиграйте с опциями эмулятора в частности подключение GPU хоста (то есть вашего компа)
3. Попробуйте с API>=15
4. Берите физический девайс - это самый верняк

Comment: вариант 2 должен помочь

Comment: 3 вариант не сработал... так же выдает эту ошибку. 4 попробую после того как найду девайс :)  1 и 2 вариант попробовать не смог из за незнания того как это сделать... если не трудно можете обьяснить ?